# Anchor Tag Not Working Properly

Tags: html, tags, anchor

I have a problem with the `anchor` tag in HTML. It takes a double-click in the link to get where I put the `anchor`, or sometimes doesn't work at all.

Here is an example:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#opt">option1</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>

<div id="opt">
```

Notice that this `id` is almost at the end of the document. Before this `div` there are other tags like sections/header's/articles/ etc.

I don't know if some of the previous stuff disturbs my `anchor` tag.

Note: surprisingly in IE it works fine. The problem is in Chrome.

Let me know, please, if more information is required.

Comment: Do you have one or more `id="opt"` in your HTML?

Comment: Hi @Badacadabra, I think Adobe Brackets it's messing things up. I opened the html from the file itself  and it worked fine. I was using the dynamic preview in Brackets, maybe it has a bug.

Comment: Maybe... Thanks for your comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<nav>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#opt">option</a></li>
       <li><a href="#opt1">option1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#opt2">option2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#opt3">option3</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>

<div id="opt">
<h1>option</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<br><br><br>
</div>
<div id="opt1">
<h1>option1</h1>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like)
</p>

<br><br><br>
</div>
<div id="opt2">
<h1>option2</h1>
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

<br><br><br>
</div>
<div id="opt3">
<p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>

<br><br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other tags won't alter the default behaviour of the anchor tag. Also, if it works in other browsers i.e. IE, I assume there is no script in your document that modify the link's behaviour as well.

Knowing that the problem arises in Chrome, I suspect a Chrome extension or sometimes the (modified) browser itself is the culprit. Please look up your browser version and extensions.

Comment: HI @Arga thanks for you comment! I will have a look on that